# GitHub no me deja hacer push a mi propio repositorio

Tags: git, github, consola

Hola tengo un problema que nunca me ha pasado, pasa que tenia un repo en una cuenta, llamemosla XX y lo que queria hacer es eliminar ese repo e inicializar uno nuevo en otra cuenta llamada YY.

### Situación:

Lo que realizé fue eliminar la carpeta git de mi carpeta del proyecto, y enseguida hice git init y cambié mis credenciales de la cuenta XX a la cuenta YY, con los comandos de `git config --global user.name` y `git config --global user.email`, ahora, procedí a hacer `git add .` luego el commit, el remote origin y por ultimo el push.

### Problema:

Me tira el siguiente error:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/********************' not found
```

PD: los asteriscos son para tapar la ruta, pero en realidad el error no viene con los asteriscos xd.

### Anotaciones:

- Ya he verificado si tengo errores de escritura en algún comando o en la url del repo y no, tengo todo correcto.
- Hasta me puse a hacer el tutorial que dice git de como subir un repo, pero aun asi nada.
- He cambiado el orden de algunos comandos por si tiene algo que ver, pero nada.

### Conclusion:

por lo que veo esto se debe a que el sistema todavia sigue en la cuenta XX y no se ha pasado a la cuenta YY, y como el repo es privado pues con razón dice que no existe, pero lo que no entiendo es si ya cambié mis credenciales, porque me sigue diciendo que no existe?.. Ya hasta le dí al link del error que me dá, y efectivamente la url está perfecta.

Estoy muy confuso, porfavor si alguien me puede ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Para todos los interesados, pasaba que **Visual Estudio Code me tenia mis credenciales de la cuenta anterior guardada**

### Solucion:

Lo que realizé fue un tutorial de la web para entrar al panel de control y eliminar las credenciales que tenia guardado mi sistema sobre git

Tutorial:
https://www.mclibre.org/consultar/informatica/lecciones/vsc-git-repositorio.html
PD: está en la ultima parte de la página.

Comment: Ayudaría que agregaras aquí los pasos hechos y solo dejes el enlace como referencia